# iterate over list of tuple pairs (python 3.x)

Tags: loops, python-3.x, tuples

i sorted files by their `date` in their `filename in a list of tuples holding each matching pair.

```
print (matching_files)
```

`output:`

```
[('sample_20140809.csv', 'data_20140809.csv'),('sample_20140806.csv', 'data_20140806.csv'), ('sample_20140801.csv', 'data_20140801.csv')
```

Question: How can I iterate over each tuple pair?

I want to open `sample_20140809.csv` `data_20140809.csv` do something to those files, write a new file and than loop to the next pair and so on until there are no more pairs in the folder ....

something like:
`for a,b in matching_pairs:` but what do I need to do If I just want to use a pair each loop ...

Comment: `for (file1, file2) in matching_files:`

Answer (score 1):

You are close, after loop you can just open the files and create a writer object of them using `csv` module :

```
import csv
for a,b in matching_pairs:
    with open(a,'w') as file_obj1,open(b,'w') as file_obj2:
        spam_writer1=csv.writer(file_obj1,delimiter=',')
        spam_writer2=csv.writer(file_obj2,delimiter=',')
        # do stuff
```

Note that you can pass your own delimiters to writer object here for example I have passed the comma as delimiter.

Read more about csv module https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: Thank you very much. That did help me quite a bit in understanding the workings. I am still not sure how to get back to the next `matching_pair` after that

Comment: @PeterS What you mean by *get back to the next matching_pair*?`matching_pair` is the name of the list of tuples and since you are using a loop it will gets to each pair in each iteration.

Comment: okay if that's how it should work than the rest of the problem is in my  `indents` I guess. Thank you very much

Comment: i still have problems with my original project regarding that problem so although the main question has been solved I`m still hanging with the loop itself ..hope links in the comments are ok : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33517691/merging-csv-file-that-are-paired-together-in-tuples-python-3-x